# Makefile find in array

Tags: makefile

If I have something like this:

```
PROJECTS += path/to/first
PROJECTS += path/to/second
PROJECTS += path/to/third
```

and

```
LIBS += lib_output/first.lib
LIBS += lib_output/second.lib
LIBS += lib_output/third.lib
```

How could I associate the project from `PROJECTS += path/to/first` with `LIBS += lib_output/first.lib`? Is there something like a hashmap available in a makefile? Or possibility to search in an array?

Comment: Make isn't really good at complex variables. Could you give us a better idea of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can simulate lookup tables using [computed variable names](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Computed-Names.html) and the fact that make variable names can include [some special characters](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Variables) like dot and forward slash:

```
PROJECTS += path/to/first
PROJECTS += path/to/second
PROJECTS += path/to/third

LIBS += lib_output/first.lib
LIBS += lib_output/second.lib
LIBS += lib_output/third.lib

lookup.path/to/first  := lib_output/first.lib
lookup.path/to/second := lib_output/second.lib
lookup.path/to/third  := lib_output/third.lib

path := path/to/first
$(info ${path} -> ${lookup.${path}})
path := path/to/second
$(info ${path} -> ${lookup.${path}})
path := path/to/third
$(info ${path} -> ${lookup.${path}})
```

Outputs:

```
$ make
path/to/first -> lib_output/first.lib
path/to/second -> lib_output/second.lib
path/to/third -> lib_output/third.lib
```

Comment: can you use it in a rule? I have rules like foo.o: randompath/foo.c, I have plenty of such files under various path, I can generate object names easily $(notdir $(SOURCES:.c=.o)), but then I cannot derive source name in pattern rule. Can I use your solution to create a single rule for them all?

Comment: You can try using [`VPATH`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search) to help make locate the sources from different directories. A better solution is to replicate the source directory hierarchy in the object directory. That would avoid filename clashes.

Comment: Good pointer. I think vpath (lowercase) is what I need. My object file name is actually 'flattened' path, e.g. some_5_steps_deep_path_foo.c.o. Much more efficient than replicating folder structure if you only cherry pick few files from each of bunch of projects.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin is there a way to do this expansion in dependency place. Like: target: $(lookup.$(path))
I find that it does not get evaluated.

Comment: @MohammadAzim There is, it is called [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Not sure how I can use it. I have 
        APPS := a b c

        lookup.a := x

        $(APPS): %: $(lookup.%).data
                echo "do something"

It gives error no rule to make target .data. i.e. perhaps $() getting evaluated before %

Comment: @MohammadAzim Post a separate question then.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43005281/variable-substitution-in-makefile-target-dependency please answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but I think the `word` function might be what you need (it may be a GNU make extension):

`$(word 2, $(PROJECTS))` returns `path/to/second`,
`$(word 2, $(LIBS))` returns `lib_output/second.lib`.