# Variable substitution in Makefile target dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile with targets that have associated dependencies. So I use lookup table like:

```
APPS = a b c

dependency.lookup.a := x
dependency.lookup.b := y
dependency.lookup.c := z

$(APPS): %: path/$(dependency.lookup.%).datafile
    do something with $(dependency.lookup.$@)
```

This makefile gives me error.
    *** No rule to make target 'path/.datafile'

Constraints: Only MinGW. can't use shell/MSYS. Also support FreeBSD.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This requires using [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion) feature:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(APPS): %: path/$$(dependency.loopup.$$*).datafile
    @echo "$@ depends on $^"

%.datafile : # Create one on demand for testing.
    mkdir -p ${@D}
    touch $@
```

Outputs:

```
mkdir -p path/
touch path/x.datafile
a depends on path/x.datafile
```

---

Alternatively, use regular dependencies:

```
a : path/x.datafile
b : path/y.datafile
c : path/z.datafile

$(APPS): % :
    @echo "$@ depends on $^"
```

The top 3 lines only add dependencies, the rule is specified separately. The output is the same.

Comment: Is it possible to add/append more dependencies in the generic rule below?

Comment: @MohammadAzim Yes, it is.

Comment: you are the man! Thanks for the help. It perfectly solves my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use regular dependencies because x is used to derive dependency as well as a command line argument. But .SECONDEXPANSION: works great!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but with rather long names. I didn't want to repeat them (in `APPS = ...`), so I used a generated auxiliary makefile.

`Makefile`:

```
all: build

include deps.mk
deps.mk: deps.txt deps.sh
    ./deps.sh <$< >$@

build: $(DEPS)
    echo "DEPS are up-to-date."  # or whatever
```

`deps.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "# This file is generated by $0"
echo "DEPS ="
while read -r dst src; do
  echo
  echo "DEPS += $dst"
  echo "$dst: $src"
  echo -e '\t''cp $< $@'  # or whatever
done
```

`deps.txt` (now only this file needs to be updated for new dependencies):

```
a x
b y
c z
```